# can anyone explain me what is the logic behind these statement

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool klsb(int num, int k) {
    return (num & (1<<(k-1)));
}

int main() {
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--) {
        int num,k;
        scanf("%d%d",&num, &k);
        cout<< klsb(num,k)<< endl;
    }
}
```

In the above code, what does

```
return (num & (1<<(k-1)));
```

mean?

Comment: Have you learned about the `&` bitwise AND operator and the `<<` bitwise shift-left operator yet? If not, I suggest you get yourself a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Basically, `klsb()` is returning true or false depending on whether a specified bit in `num` is set to 1 or 0.

Comment: @NathanOliver There should be a medal I could nominate you for that edit. I gave up immediately.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks.  Wasn't too bad.  I've got a user script that lets me highlight a code block and then press tab to indent it all.  Comes in really useful.

Comment: It is [ill advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) to put `using namespace std` in your code. If you absolutely must save source code characters, limit the scope of the statement to something like `using std::cout`

Answer (score 2):

`a & b` is bitwise AND. The result will be a number where all bits that are 1 in `a` and `b` will be one and all other bits will be zero. Eg `101 & 110 = 100`

`a << b` is binary shift left. It will take the bits of `a` and shift them to the left by `b` positions filling with zeros from the right and discarding the overflow. Eg `1011 << 1 = 0110`

The statement in your code will create a number where bit `k-1` is set (`1 << (k-1)`) and then AND it with `num`. The result is a number != 0 iff bit `k-1` is set in num. This will then be casted to bool. Since any value != 0 is boolean `true` in C++ this function tests wether or not bit `k-1` is `1` in `num`

Answer (score 0):

You use `&` as a bitwise AND, `1 << k-1` means that 1 is bit-shifted to the left by the amount of `k-1`:

`$a & $b`
And: Bits that are set in both `$a` and `$b` are set.

`$a << $b`
Shift left: Shift the bits of `$a` `$b` steps to the left (each step means "multiply by two")

Example:

1001 & 1000 = 1000 (the first 1 is in both)

11001<<2 = 1100100 (shifted 2 to the left)